# mp4 files dont work properly on chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, video, vaadin, mp4

I have 10 MP4 files which I am embedding in my application. When I open my application in Edge, i am able to play all the 10 files smoothly, but in chrome, they don't work properly. I have to refresh the browser couple of time, to make them work.
Though, they work fine if I open the MP4 link directly on chrome.Any idea why they don't work properly on chrome. I am using Vaadin to build my application

I also noticed, if keep only 6 videos, then they work fine. If I put more than 6, then I start seeing the issue

Comment: Are you able to share a link of an example video with this problem?

Comment: I am really sorry, but I cant share the video. Though I found this to be a known issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249578/chrome-hangs-on-loading-page-with-many-video-tags

Comment: can you check the browser console and application logs for errors ?

Comment: Not sure how i can I use the suggested solution in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be a known issue stackoverflow.com/questions/25249578